# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs (PayUMoney integration)

Tags: android, gradle, build, payu

I am trying to integrate PayUMoney payment gateway in my app. The very first line of the integration documentation says to add -

`compile 'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.0.0'`

in my app-level build.gradle file dependecies. But as soon as I do this i encounter an error -

Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs also the line -

implementation `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'`

show the following error -

```
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 26.1.0, 23.2.1. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0 and com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion.)
```

Help me resolve this issue.

**Below is my build.gradle(Module:app) code** -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.learnturtle.payucheck"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}



dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    compile 'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: I also faced this error while integrating a payment gateway in my app and it turned out that the gateway needed some classes to be ignored in proguard file. So you can check the documentation of payu and confirm that you are not missing something there.

Comment: I feel the documentation is quite brief..

Comment: https://www.payumoney.com/dev-guide/mobilecheckout/android.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the latest dependency

```
compile 'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.5.0'
```

and change minSdkversion

```
minSdkVersion 20
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the latest dependency

```
compile 'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.6.0'
```

and change minSdkversion

```
minSdkVersion 20
```

and in Manifest add this

```
tools:replace="android:allowBackup,android:usesCleartextTraffic"
```

Answer (score 0):

check gradle console in this case , maybe there is manifest issue / values which is already present in the support libs, or sdk version compatibiliy issue, you will get the whole detail of the error.

Answer (score 0):

> Compile with following sdk

```
 implementation 'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.5.0'
```

> in same app label gradle

```
 minSdkVersion 20
```

**Open manifest and make change inside application tag**

```
tools:replace="android:allowBackup"


 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
    tools:replace="android:allowBackup">
```

> it worked for me fine.